# * in tabular LaTeX table displaying error in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to create a LaTeX table using Rmarkdown. The table seems to working fine in LaTeX, but when I set it up on Rmarkdown, it is throwing up the following error:

```
processing file: table_5.Rmd
output file: table_5.knit.md

! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> table_5.tex
```

I think the issue maybe arissing from the `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }` where both the curly brackets are asterisk are used together. Could anyone suggest a way to go around this issue in Rmarkdown?

The code to reproduce the issue is as follows:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{rotating} 
- \newcommand\mytabC[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
- \newcommand\mytabL[1]{\hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
---

\clearpage
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. }
\label{tab:my-tab5}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
\toprule
  &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 4} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
  Occupational class &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI          &
    Coefficient          & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's occupational class at age 5}} & \\
   Female ($N=2{,}980$) & \\
   \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.004\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.009, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & 0.025; 0.025 & & 0.003; 0.004 & & 0.002; 0.002 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}925$) & \\
  \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ -0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.36\\ 1.01}} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.743; 0.568 & & 0.123; 0.045 & & 0.411; <0.001 & & 0.261; 0.408 \\

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5}} & \\
  Female ($N=2{,}485$) & \\
  \mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ A-level/equiv.\\ \hspace{2mm}Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & <0.001; 0.008 & & <0.001; 0.002 & & 0.005; 0.001 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}412$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 1.46} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
    \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
       & 0.304; 0.064 & & 072; 0.046 & & 0.160; 0.305 & & 0.078; — \\

  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's highest qualification at age 5}} \\ 
Female ($N=2{,}343$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ -0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ -0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
   & 0.304; 0.064 & & 0.899; 0.698 & & 0.715; 0.368 & & 0.642; 0.287 \\
\addlinespace
Female ($N=2{,}286$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.002\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.002\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.08\\ 0.00\\ -0.08} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.80\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.123; 0.020 & & 0.003; <0.001 & & 0.056; 0.009 & & 0.986; 0.866 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}     
\item[a] Duis leo ante, malesuada sit amet magna at, dictum feugiat dui; 
\item[b] CI: Confidence Interval; 
\item[c] P-value: p-value from a likelihood ratio test of the overall association; 
\item[d] P-trend: p-value not presented for relationship where there was significant deviation from linearity
\end{tablenotes}    
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that rmarkdown is not clever enough to correctly parse the `#` in your custom command. You can avoid the problem by hiding the definitions in a .tex file and input this file:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: true
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{rotating} 
- \input{preamble}
---

\clearpage
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\scriptsize
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ornare diam erat, quis accumsan massa congue bibendum. }
\label{tab:my-tab5}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c} }
\toprule
  &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 4} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} 
  Occupational class &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI          &
    Coefficient          & 95\% CI\tnote{b} &
    Coefficient\tnote{a} & 95\% CI\tnote{b} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's occupational class at age 5}} & \\
   Female ($N=2{,}980$) & \\
   \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.004\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.009, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & 0.025; 0.025 & & 0.003; 0.004 & & 0.002; 0.002 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}925$) & \\
  \mytabL{I Professional/II Intermediate\\ III Skilled (non-manual\ or manual)\\ IV Partly skilled/V Unskilled} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ -0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.36\\ 1.01}} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.743; 0.568 & & 0.123; 0.045 & & 0.411; <0.001 & & 0.261; 0.408 \\

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Mother's highest qualification at age 5}} & \\
  Female ($N=2{,}485$) & \\
  \mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ A-level/equiv.\\ \hspace{2mm}Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & <0.001; <0.001 & & <0.001; 0.008 & & <0.001; 0.002 & & 0.005; 0.001 \\
\addlinespace
  Female ($N=2{,}412$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00}} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 1.46} &
    \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
    \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
    \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
       & 0.304; 0.064 & & 072; 0.046 & & 0.160; 0.305 & & 0.078; — \\

  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Father's highest qualification at age 5}} \\ 
Female ($N=2{,}343$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ -0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ -0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
   & 0.304; 0.064 & & 0.899; 0.698 & & 0.715; 0.368 & & 0.642; 0.287 \\
\addlinespace
Female ($N=2{,}286$) & \\
\mytabL{Vocational/degree and higher\\ 
        A-level/equiv.\\ 
        Vocational/O-level/equiv.\\ 
        No qualification} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.002\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.002\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.00\\ 0.00\\ 0.00} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.00} &
  \mytabC{0.00 (ref)\\ 0.08\\ 0.00\\ -0.08} &
  \mytabC{—\\ 0.00, 0.00\\ 0.00, 0.80\\ 0.00, 0.00} \\
  \hspace{2.5mm}$p$-values (overall\tnote{c}; test for trend\tnote{d}) &
    & 0.123; 0.020 & & 0.003; <0.001 & & 0.056; 0.009 & & 0.986; 0.866 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}     
\item[a] Duis leo ante, malesuada sit amet magna at, dictum feugiat dui; 
\item[b] CI: Confidence Interval; 
\item[c] P-value: p-value from a likelihood ratio test of the overall association; 
\item[d] P-trend: p-value not presented for relationship where there was significant deviation from linearity
\end{tablenotes}    
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

with `preamble.tex`:

```
\newcommand\mytabC[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mytabL[1]{\hspace{5mm}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
```